# passing data from model to view via controller

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an MVC pattern in my android whack-a-mole game.

I'm generating mole locations in the model via an inner class thread and want to eventually pass it to the view so that it would generate a sprite for it.

how do I create a way for my view to continuously receive the generated mole locations from my model?

I've edited my code below to capture the essentials behind them.

**MODEL :**

```
public class GameModel{
   public GameModel(){
      spawner = new MoleSpawner();
      spawner.start();
   }
.
.
.
   private class MoleSpawner extends Thread{
      private int location;
      public void run() {
          location = new Random().nextInt(20);
          try{
             sleep (1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
   }
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
public GameView{
.
.
.
  public void createMoleSprite(int newlocation){
     //create sprites here
     //newlocation should come from the MODEL
     //this method must be triggered everytime the MODEL creates a new location
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try to be honest and helpful - the first time you try MVC you won't follow it correctly. I know I didn't. So don't focus so much on MVC - focus on making it work. Once you make things work, you will notice how you could've been more MVC about it; but don't let the idea of "i'm not following MVC" be a stopping block in your code.

Comment: @Shark, very true! I've experienced this many times where I start off with MVC, put some of my model code in the controllers, some in the models, some in the views and move them all around to the right place once I've got the whole thing working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways you can implement this is by using Handlers.

It can be more complex, but I'll give you a simple example on how to implement this.

In the Activity where your game is running, get it's Handler by using

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

Then, when you instantiate your model, pass it the mHandler object as well as a reference to your activity. In your model, whenever you need to spawn a new mole, do

```
 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

   gameActivity.spawnNewMoleAt(location);


 });
```

This can become a lot more complex, expecially if you control the rate at which moles are spawned dynamically, but you can build on this.

You can find a good tutorial on Handlers [HERE](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).

Comment: does this mean that the data will go straight from the model to view, bypassing the controller?

Comment: No, Handlers are used to send messages the Activity - usually to manipulate UI elements from a non-UI thread. This is really android specific and has nothing to do with the MVC paradigm.

Still a good suggestion thouhg

Comment: Yeah, but you can also pass the handler to the controller and post from there as well.

Comment: @Shark, not really. Handlers are used to send messages from one thread to another. It doesn't matter whether the receiving thread is a UI thread or not. It's just that Handlers make it very convenient to make UI changes to an Activity from a background thread.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: @Vinay S Shenoy I said 'usually' :) as in 'i usually use them for that purpose when runOnUiThread() isn't what I want' :D thanks for the heads-up though, it'll do him good.

Comment: @Shark, Ah, I took it that you meant the "official" use for Handlers is for updating UI. I have never actually used runOnUiThread().. Handlers have always been more convenient for me.. To each, his own, I guess.. :D